# Second hard drive isn't recognized in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup

I have an old laptop that the motherboard went out of.  I have 10 gigs of pictures I want to rescue so I took the HDD out and put it in my main computer.  I hooked it up via a sata to USB port, and I have tried hooking it up straight into my motherboard (I have alternated now that it's not working).  Anyways I got it hooked up with the sata to USB and it showed up and I could access my pictures.

I tried transferring them to a 16 gig USB stick and after a few minutes I heard *ding* as if the usb got knocked loose.  It popped up on screen to format my hard drive before use.  I obviously didn't so I wouldn't lose my photos.  Since then I cannot get the hard drive to be recognized by my computer.  It shows up in Device Manager.  In Disk Management it shows as `Disk 1, Unknown, Not Initialized`.